# What does the letter 'P' at the end of an author's pseudonym mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, names, internet-slang

There are many authors on YouTube and NicoNico whose names end with the letter 'P', for example: 鼻そうめんP, 無力P, etc. What does this 'P' stand for? Why do they all use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That P (simply read ピー) stands for プロデューサー ("**P**roducer"). Traditionally, P has been used like a name suffix for a super-high executive in the showbiz/broadcasting/anime industry (someone even higher than a "D", or 監督/director). However, after the success of the [*Idolm@aster* franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster), where a "producer" has a role closer to that of an agent or a manager, this "P" suddenly became a very common suffix for amateur creators on YouTube and Nicovideo. You can read more about this on [this Nicopedia article](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC) (in Japanese).

> #### 日本の放送業界におけるプロデューサー
>
> 日本ではテレビ・ラジオ番組における最高責任者である。
>
> #### ニコニコ動画におけるプロデューサー
>
> ニコニコ動画では動画製作者、及び動画投稿者（通称：うｐ主）の名前、動画タグに「（名前）P」と表記される。この「P」はproducerのP。
>
> アイドルマスターではプレイヤーの名前が「（名前）P」と表示されるため(当初は画面加工の少ないコミュ動画やノーマルPVが多かった)同じ動画投稿者の動画の集約、及び他の投稿者の動画との区別のためタグへの表記が自然発生した。
>
> VOCALOIDやUTAU等の歌唱合成ソフトを用いた楽曲や、MikuMikuDanceを用いた動画の投稿者に対しても形を変えて持ち込まれている。VOCALOID系動画投稿者では最初に「(名前)P」 が命名されたのはワンカップP（2007年9月頃）であると言われる。ただし、この呼び方が一般化するまでには数ヶ月かかったため、黎明期から活躍している 動画投稿者ではP名が付いていなかったり、あるいは後に付いてもあまり使用されないといった場合が比較的多い（例：OSTER project、ika、kz、 ryo）。
>
> 一般社会におけるプロデューサーとは「製作総指揮者」であるが、アイドルマスターにおける「プロデューサー」は必ずしもそうではなく、マネージャー の様だったり飼い主やポケモントレーナーの様だったりさまざまである。

Answer (score 3):

It stands for "Producer".

It originates in Idol Master, which is a video game you will play a producer to train pop stars. And then music/video creators especially in niconico (Vocaloid etc) started to be called with P.

You can find some posts/dics with these words

P名 (P-mei: P-name)

アイマス (aimasu (Japanese abbreviation for Idol Master))

由来 (yurai: Derivation)